# How can you set a timezone in an outlook.com link?

Tags: email, outlook, calendar, outlook.com, outlook-calendar

I'm trying to set correct times for an Outlook event in the UK, but Outlook seems to set the incorrect time for BST (British Summer Time).

Here is a link, which creates an event for 19th June 2017 at 1254pm to 1257pm.

In my Outlook it opens an hour ahead as 1354pm. Is there a way to explicitly set the timezone in the link?

I've tried checking my settings and using a different Outlook account so I don't think it's an issue with my mail/calendar settings.

https://bay02.calendar.live.com/calendar/calendar.aspx?rru=addevent&dtstart=20170619T125400&dtend=20170619T125700&summary=Summary+of+the+event&location=Location+of+the+event&description=example+text.&allday=false&uid=

Answer (score 1):

After researching quite I've realised that Outlook always expresses time in UTC when sending a link. Therefore you need to convert the date/time from BST to UTC. You can do this with PHP like this:

```
$date = new DateTime('2017-06-22T12:54', new 
DateTimeZone('Europe/London')); /* <-- Time zone to be converted */

echo $date->format('YmdHis') . "\n";$date->setTimezone(new 
DateTimeZone('UTC'));echo $date->format('YmdHis') . "\n"; /* <-- New time zone, UTC */
```